# Why PCA returns empty Coeff and Score?

Tags: matlab, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I am applying PCA on a dataset consist of 2340 (label excluded) features and 2245 records (2245X2340 double matrix), to reduce its high dimensionality and to select at least 50 features for further classification process with the following codes on Matlab:

```matlab
[coeff,score,~,~,~,mu] = pca(X);
save("coeff.mat","coeff");
reducedDimension = coeff(:,1:50);
reducedData = X * reducedDimension;
```

but at first line on breakpoint it just returns coeff and score empty:

[image: Workspace variables]

and when reaches to third line stops with this error:

[image: Command window Error image]

Where is the problem?
Secondly is this way of using PCA (code above) true for dimensionality reduction?

dataset was a bit large so i just posted screenshot of a portion of it:
[image]

Comment: check if you data contains `NaN`s and please create a [minimal *reproducible* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with some exemplary data for us to test. Otherwise, we are obliged to speculate

Comment: yes there are some feature columns with almost NaN value, does this cause a problem?

Comment: yes, there is no correlation defined for this

Comment: thanks :)) , that was it, i just replaced Nan values with 0 by simple line of code: X(isnan(X))=0; and I ran PCA again and it worked well.

Comment: great! Just keep in mind that replacing `NaN`s with zeros may suggest wrong correlations to the PCA

Comment: I know I just wanted to test it, that it's the only problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have NANs in your dataset. First you have to convert your NANs to numeric values so that the numeric behaviour of the data will be remain constant.
To do this, just add the following line in your code before applying PCA:

```
data(isnan(data))=0;
```

This will assign 0 to all the NANs values